ERROR WHEN TRYIN TO UPDATE A DASHBOARD POWER BI (Npgsql) - Esp/Eng
I trying to update a dashboard in power BI, but I get this error

Tipo actividad new (this is the name of a measure/table) Se produjo un
error al leer datos desde el proveedor:
'Npgsql.Tls.ClientAlertException: CertificateUnknown: Server
certificate was not accepted. Chain status: Se procesó correctamente
una cadena de certificados, pero termina en un certificado de raíz no
compatible con el proveedor de confianza. . en
Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.SendAlertFatal(AlertDescription
description, String message) en
Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[] buf, Int32&
pos) en Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandshakeMessages() en
Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.d__43.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción --- en 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() en
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task) en
Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.d__72.MoveNext()

Error Eng
Tipo actividad new
An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Npgsql.Tls.ClientAlertException: CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. Chain status: Se procesó correctamente una cadena de certificados, pero termina en un certificado de raíz no compatible con el proveedor de confianza. . at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.SendAlertFatal(AlertDescription description, String message) at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[] buf, Int32& pos) at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandshakeMessages() at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.<GetInitialHandshakeMessages>d__43.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.<PerformInitialHandshake>d__72.MoveNext()'

I get that same message for different tables or measures.The data is obtained from an Amazon server and this error is recent, since previously it did not have it.

Please don't SHOUT at us. That's rude. Also please change your regional settings so you get the error messages in English.

I usually write titles in capital letters, sorry if that hurts you.
